# Intelligencia Redirect URL

Tags: asp.net, web-config, redirect

I'm on IIS 7 and trying to redirect a URL for example www.domainname.co.uk/something to www.domain.co.uk but it doesn't seem to be hitting it in the web.config.

```
<redirect url="domain.co.uk/something/" to="http://www.newdomain.co.uk"/>
```

Any ideas why it's not hitting?

Comment: where are you getting this syntax from? It's incorrect. IIS does not have a `<redirect url="" to="" />` element.

Comment: @Dai He uses an [external rewriting component](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Intelligencia.UrlRewriter), therefore the non-IIS-conform syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS uses `<httpRedirect>` with a variety of child elements to achieve the required effect, if necessary.

It's documented here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

In the filesystem directory corresponding to the `/something/` path for your `domain.co.uk` website, add a web.config file with this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newdomain.co.uk" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note that your `domain.co.uk/something/` and `newdomain.co.uk/` directories cannot share this web.config otherwise it will cause an infinite redirection loop. If you want canonical domain names then I recommend using the URL Rewrite module instead, which provides redirection abilities in addition to URL rewriting.